# $1\le p \lt \infty$ and $f_k$ nonnegative increasing. Then $f_k\to f$ in $L_p$ iff $\sup_k||f_k||_p \lt \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $1\le p \lt \infty$ and $0\le f_k$ increasing to $f$, and $f_k$ measurable.

Then $f_k\to f$ in $L_p$ if and only if $\sup_k||f_k||_p \lt \infty$.

I was able to show the if part, but I can't show the only if part. How can I show this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: It is enough to show that the set $A_k: = \left\{ {f_k \left( x \right):x \in Dom\left( f \right)} \right\}$ is bounded in $L_p$. Since $f_k$ increases positive and $
\mathop {\sup }\limits_k \left\| {f_k } \right\|_p 
< \infty$  then the set is bounded.

Comment: @mwomath I'm sorry I wrote the question wrong. I can't show the only if part, that is if $f_k \to f$ in $L_p$ then $\sup_k ||f_k||_p \lt \infty$.

Comment: from if part $f_k  \to f$ this is equivalent to say $\left\| {f_k  - f} \right\|_p  \to 0$ which means that $
\mathop {\sup }\limits_k \left\| {f_k } \right\|_p < \infty$

Comment: @mwomath how do I actually show that $||f||_p \lt \infty$? I just can't show this other than resorting to the fact that $L_p$ is Banach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the monotone convergence theorem, you always will have
$$\int f^p = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int f_k^p$$
Taking $p$th roots (and using continuity of the function $x \rightarrow x^{1 \over p}$), one therefore has
$$||f||_p = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} ||f_k||_p \tag 1$$
Since the $f_k$ increase to $f$, the limit in $(1)$ is an increasing limit.
So one also has 
$$||f||_p = \sup_k ||f_k||_p \tag 2$$
If each $f_k \in L^p$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} ||f_k - f||_p = 0$, which I'm taking as your assumption, then $f \in L^p$ since by the triangle inequality one has $||f||_p \leq ||f - f_k||_p + ||f_k||_p$. Hence $(2)$ gives that $\sup_k ||f_k||_p = ||f||_p$ is finite.

(You do need each $f_k \in L^p$ for this; otherwise you could just take $f_k = f$ to be equal to some non-$L^p$ function for all $k$ and the problem will be false).

Answer (score -1):

Well, fk is a sequence of increasing functions to f, so with sufficient work you should be able to show that sup(k) ||fk||p = ||f||p.

Comment: Yes I can show that but how does that show that it is finite?

Comment: If you can show that sup(k) ||fk||p = ||f||p, then you can show that ||f||p is finite from the assumption above. From there, because fk is increasing, ||fk||p is, so the supremum of ||fk||p is the same as the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I just read your updated version of the question.

If fk->f in Lp, we know that f is in Lp. Considering fk is a non-negative increasing sequence of functions, to converge at f it must be that sup(k) ||fk||p=||f||p. f is in Lp, so ||f||p is finite.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It would be nice if you format your answers so that they are better received.

Comment: How can I show that $f \in L_p$ other than using the fact that $L_p$ is Banach? I mean how can I show that $\int |f|^p \lt \infty$?